# All English characters into an array

Tags: php, arrays

How to get array containing all English characters in php?

One way is to write down all 26 letters completely in the array, but it seems stupid.

Any php function or other ways to do the job?

```
<?php 
    // stupid ?
    $arr= array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
        'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy with [`range()`](http://php.net/range):

```
$arr = range( 'a', 'z');
```

That's all you need.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from @nickb's great answer, there are heaps of ways. You could use the ASCII table and find lowercase letters by their index in the ASCII table, but it's pretty obtuse.

```
$ascii_lowercase_alphabet = array();
for($i=97; $i<=122; $i++) {
    $ascii_lowercase_alphabet[] = chr($i);
}
```

If you're trying to search for these characters in another string, you could consider a regular expression using a range like `preg_match('/[a-z]+/', $string);` or `preg_match('/[A-Za-z]+/', $string);` to include uppercase.

I guess finding the best way depends why you want to define the array in the first place.